# Changing OS parameters from Java source code

Tags: java, windows, linux

Can I design my program so that it will automatically change OS's hotkeys parameters? I mean, when installing a program, it will set the hotkey of OS so that if you press them, the program itself would run. (Linux/Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your program should reside permanently in memory and should be loaded as system starts, then it will listen for keys pressed. Pure Java don't have possibilities to monitor key press, but you can write or use existing library, written, say, in C++, that will listen for keys pressed and pass it to your deamon Java application. That external library can be coupled with your Java application by means of JNI.